# Properly convert a gimp image using ImageMagick

Tags: makefile, imagemagick

I am having problems using ImageMagick to convert gimp files to png. As you can see from the picture below, the black and white scale is flipped or some kind of whitening effect is applied to the image output by ImageMagick. So how can I get ImageMagick to properly convert gimp images?

[image: Example of Fail]

I have tried multiple output formats and the same thing occurs in each, the image output does not match the one I made in gimp.

I am using ImageMagick because this is being ran from a makefile, and ImageMagick works quite nicely in this application. The makefile rule is the below command.

```
%.png: %.xcf
    convert $< -layers merge $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to use the `xcf2png`, part of the `xcftools` package. It seems to solve the problem. Only problem is that this program writes the converted file on stdout, so you need to redirect the output.

```
xcf2png $< > $@
```

<strike>I figured out that in order to properly convert gimp image with Imagemagick the following command is necessary.</strike>

```
convert $< -background rgba\(0,0,0,0\) -layers merge $@
```